# differentiate figure caption from the one that is used in index

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I use this code to specify an image:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{nameOfImage}
    \caption{long descriptive text}
\end{figure}
```

When I create an index of all figures, that long descriptive text gets stuffed into the index. I would like to keep the text below the image as it is now, and use some other text in the index of figures. That long descriptive text is just too long. Which command should I use?

Comment: What about: `\caption[LOF caption]{long caption}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\caption` macro already has a short option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
 \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
    \caption[short text]{long descriptive text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '\caption' tag:
'\caption["This Text Belongs To Index"]{"This Text Belongs To Figure/Table Caption"}'.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What you wrote adds nothing to the already existing answer.